# Confused about using populate with mongoose and prefilling data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm a noob and have created a collection - Appointment - which has a field in it called staff.

Staff is a separate collection and has an id.

I'm trying to show a list of all Appointments, and create a select dropdown, which allows me to change the staff member.

I'm confused as I am only setting the Appointment.staff to the staff._id of that particular staff member, but I want the select dropdown to show their name.

I think I need to use 'populate', but as I'm a noob I'm not sure.

How can I do this?

Here is the controller for the Appointment list

```
angular.module('MyApp')
.controller('adminController', ['$scope', 'Appointment', '$state', '$rootScope' , '$stateParams', '$log', '$modal', 'Staff',  function($scope, Appointment, $state, $rootScope, $stateParams, $log, $modal, Staff) {

$scope.apps  = Appointment.query();
$scope.staffList = Staff.query();

}])
```

The code for the dropdown:

```
 <td>
      <select  class="form-control" name="staff" 
             ng-options="staff._id as staff.name for staff in staffList" 
             ng-model="app.staff" 
             ng-change="selectChange(app)"
                            >
         <option></option>
      </select>
</td>
```

and the schemas for the Appointment

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Creates the appointments Schema for the User details

var appointmentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String, 
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  address_1: String,
  address_2: String,
  city: String,
  postcode: String,
  phone: String,
  appointment_date: String, 
  token: String, 
  StripeCustomerId: String, 
  total_time: Number,
  total_charge: Number,
  lat: Number,
  lng: Number,
  staff: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Staff' }],
  jobDone: { type: Boolean, default: false}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Appointment', appointmentSchema);
```

and the Staff

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Creates the appointments Schema for the Staff details

var staffSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String, 
  email: { type: String, unique: true },
  phone: Number,
  signup_date: Date,
  jobs: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Appointments' }],
  total_paid: { type: Number, default: 0 }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Staff', staffSchema);
```

Comment: Instead of having the staff.ID in the Appt schema, have an array of staff.Names (because more than one staff could be a part of an appointment)